# Execute javascript (katex) on tinymce content

Tags: javascript, html, dom, electron, tinymce

I am creating a small desktop editor based on electron.js and tinymce.
For university I also want to be able to render latex equations inside tinymce. Unfortunately I cannot access the tinymce-iframe via js.

I included both katex.js as well as tinymce.js in my html file.
Both of them work fine if separated. Latex equations in the body are rendered and tinymce loads and works too.

The editor is placed inside if an iframe:

```
<div class="tox-edit-area">
    <iframe id="editor_ifr" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"
        title="Rich-Text-Bereich. Drücken Sie Alt+0 für Hilfe." class="tox-edit-area__iframe">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Inside of this iframe is the actual editor-textfield:

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body id="tinymce" class="mce-content-body " data-id="editor" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">
      <p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Accessing the body via `document.querySelector("#tinymce")` as well as the `getElementByID` and the jquery version of those functions always give me an `undefinded` / `null` result.

For latex rendering I call the `renderMathInElement(document.body)` from katex, which works fine after starting my application.

The strange part is, after accessing the iframe via dev console (inspecting the element) I get the correct result with `document.querySelector("#tinymce")` but the I cannot access the `renderMath...` functions from katex any more. I assume, this is beacause the katex script is not available inside the iframe and the chrome devtool knows when I am inside of an iframe.

Is there a way to access iframe contents via js from the outer file?